# Adding a variable based on values in another table

Tags: r

I have two tables.
The first  lists all the individuals.

```
IND
1
2
3
4
5
```

The rows of the second table are the moves (from a place to another) made by each of individuals (every individuals made one or more moves). First column is the IND number; the two others are place of origin (PLACE_A) (A, B, or C) and the place of destination (PLACE_B) (A, B, or C).

```
IND PLACE_A PLACE_B
1   A   B
1   B   A
1   A   C
2   C   A
2   A   C
3   B   A
3   A   C
3   C   A
3   A   C
3   C   A
4   C   A
4   A   C
4   C   A
4   A   C
5   B   C
5   C   A
```

I want to have a new column in the first table which will tells me whereas an individual has ever been in a specific place (let’s say B). I can’t figure out.

```
IND LIVED_B
1   TRUE
2   FALSE
3   TRUE
4   FALSE
5   TRUE
```

Comment: Did you meant `library(dplyr);tbl2 %>% group_by(IND) %>% summarise(LIVED_B = ("B" %in% PLACE_B)|"B" %in% PLACE_A)`

Comment: In my opinion, this is a poor data format. Why not have the second table be IND and PLACE with the sequence of places implicit in the ordering of rows? For a third column, maybe add a sequence/time variable. In that case, this all simplifies.

Comment: Please consider accepting one answer as correct.

Comment: @Frank In fact my second table contains many informations related to each move. I just gave a simplified version here so that the problem is much more understandable.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

With data.table...

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF2)

indDT   = data.table(IND = 1:5)
placeDT = data.table(PLACE = LETTERS[1:3])
DT      = DF2[, .(PLACE = c(PLACE_A, PLACE_B[.N])), by=IND][, T := rowid(IND)][]
```

Then to see if each person has been in each place...

```
DT[, table(
  IND   = factor(IND, levels = indDT$IND), 
  PLACE = factor(PLACE, levels = placeDT$PLACE)
) > 0L ]

   PLACE
IND    A     B    C
  1 TRUE  TRUE TRUE
  2 TRUE FALSE TRUE
  3 TRUE  TRUE TRUE
  4 TRUE FALSE TRUE
  5 TRUE  TRUE TRUE
```

The `factor` calls ensure that all levels are shown, even if there are places no one in the data set visits.

Comment: Sorry, i am a newbie in R but the following commands cannot be executed: "setDT(DF2)" and "DT      = DF2[, .(PLACE = c(PLACE_A, PLACE_B[.N])), by=IND][, T := rowid(IND)][]"

Comment: @F.Lyon I'm not sure I follow. I'm using `DF2` to mean the same thing as `tab2` from Daniel's answer. If you have the data.table package loaded, I think those commands should work..?

Answer (score 1):

First, I put the data into data.frames:

```
IND = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
tab1 = as.data.frame(list('IND' = IND, 
                          'LIVED_B' = rep(FALSE, length(IND))))
tab2 = as.data.frame(list('IND'=c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5),
                          'PLACE_A'=c("A", "B", "A", "C", "A", "B", "A", "C", "A", "C", "C", "A", "C", "A", "B", "C"),
                          'PLACE_B'=c("B", "A", "C", "A", "C", "A", "C", "A", "C", "A", "A", "C", "A", "C", "C", "A")))
```

I would consider renaming the columns `PLACE_A` and `PLACE_B` if these `A` and `B` are not related to the locations *A*, *B*, and *C*.

### solution

```
tab1$LIVED_B[tab2$IND[tab2$PLACE_A=='B']] = TRUE
```

Result:

```
  IND LIVED_B
1   1    TRUE
2   2   FALSE
3   3    TRUE
4   4   FALSE
5   5    TRUE
```

### another solution

We might now want to consider place C (without having declared the column `LIVED_C` previously):

```
tab1$LIVED_C[tab2$IND[tab2$PLACE_A=='C']] = TRUE
tab1$LIVED_C[is.na(tab1$LIVED_C)] = FALSE
```

Result:

```
  IND LIVED_B LIVED_C
1   1    TRUE   FALSE
2   2   FALSE    TRUE
3   3    TRUE    TRUE
4   4   FALSE    TRUE
5   5    TRUE    TRUE
```

### consider columns PLACE_A and PLACE_B

If you also want to consider places where the individual currently lives (consider PLACE_A and PLACE_B columns):

```
tab1$LIVED_or_STILL_LIVES_A[tab2$IND[as.logical((tab2$PLACE_A=='A') + (tab2$PLACE_B=='A'))]] = TRUE
tab1$LIVED_or_STILL_LIVES_A[is.na(tab1$LIVED_or_STILL_LIVES_A)] = FALSE
```

Result:

```
  IND LIVED_B LIVED_C LIVED_or_STILL_LIVES_A
1   1    TRUE   FALSE                   TRUE
2   2   FALSE    TRUE                   TRUE
3   3    TRUE    TRUE                   TRUE
4   4   FALSE    TRUE                   TRUE
5   5    TRUE    TRUE                   TRUE
```

Comment: This works well if every individuals of tab1 has corresponding information in tab2 but in my table which is much bigger, there are a lot of individuals who never migrated...I think a link thus need to be established between the two tables through the IND variable..right?

Comment: Re `x[idx] <- TRUE; x[is.na(x)] <- FALSE` you could simplify to initialize to FALSE, like `x <- FALSE; x[idx] <- TRUE` instead of testing NA, I think..

Answer (score 0):

I believe Frank's answer is a good one, maybe another option is to use a nested select, but this would work only for one column, as your question says.

```
SELECT 1 IND INTO #T1
INSERT INTO #T1 VALUES 
(2), (3), (4), (5)

SELECT 1 IND, 'A' PLACE_A, 'B' PLACE_B INTO #T2
INSERT INTO #T2 VALUES 
(1, 'B', 'A'), (1, 'A', 'C'), (2, 'C', 'A'), (2, 'B', 'A'), (2, 'A', 'C'), (3, 'B', 'A'), (3, 'C', 'A'), (3, 'A', 'C')

SELECT A.IND, A.LIVED_A FROM 
(SELECT A.IND, CASE WHEN PLACE_A = 'A' THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END LIVED_A
FROM #T1 A INNER JOIN #T2 B ON A.IND = B.IND) A
WHERE A.LIVED_A = 'TRUE' GROUP BY A.IND, A.LIVED_A
```

Regards!